# Displaying a value every time a button is clicked

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I would like to know how to display a value in a `TEdit` every time a button is clicked.

For example:

```
iNumber := 1;
```

If I click the button 4 times, the edit must display `'1111'`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I gave you a quick answer below, but I also feel that I should point out that we typically require posters to include their own attempts in their questions. So please have that in mind for your future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could easily convert your number to string and add it to previous text of TEdit:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := Edit1.Text + IntToStr(iNumber);
end;
```